# Hlookup to get the value of the entire row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

I am trying to use `Hlookup` to get the value of the entire row and show blank if not found from worksheet 1 to worksheet 2

[image]

I was trying to use this formula

```
=IFERROR(HLOOKUP(A1,Sheet1!1:2,2,0),"")
```

but this formula doesn't allow me to drag it down

Comment: what value from the row (from worksheet 1) you want to show in worksheet 2 ? which column ?

Comment: since you are not replying, I would use some kind of version of the following formula `=IF(ISNA(HLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$2:$4,2,FALSE)),"",HLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$2:$4,2,FALSE))`  , if you want to use the first parameter "value" with reference to cell A2, then put this formula in abother column (than column A)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you need :

`=IFERROR(HLOOKUP(A$1,Sheet1!$A$1:$I$4,ROW(A2),0),"")`

Put that in A2 then drag that down (and across if you need)...

Comment: @ MacroMarc thanks this is perfect know i have learned how to use Row, is there any chance that you can give me macro

Comment: Glad to help. What sort of macro do you mean? If it is another situation, then its appropraite to ask another question and somebody can help?

Comment: it is actually same situation instead of formula if there is macro to run, then there is no need for me to put formula and drag in every cell